# The behaviour of the critical F per F distribution

Tags: anova, f-distribution

I noticed that, for increasing degrees of freedom of the MSE (Mean square error / denominator in the F-ratio), the critical F declines. This is also the case for increasing degrees of freedom of the MSG (Mean square between groups / nominator in the F-ratio), but only if you have at least 3 degrees of freedom for MSE, otherwise it increases. Can someone explain to me why the F-distributions behave in such a peculiar way? A pure mathematical explanation is beyond my scope, but an intuitive or mathematics-light explanation will do!

Comment: I suggest taking a look at mean and variance of F distribution - and at how mean and variance change with both degrees of freedom.